# Why is the last row not returned on Excel import?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I'm using OleDbConnection with the following connection string:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "'{0}'" + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;'";
```

I'm importing the Excel file into an OleDbDataReader and then using reader.Read() to read in the rows, as follows:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   // import row
}
```

For some reason, the last row of the Excel file is always missing in the import. I've tried it with several different Excel files, but it has never worked. Out of desperation, I've also tried iterating one more time after the loop ends, but it tells me there is no more data. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: very classic looping error seems like.
Do you somehow have in your code getting out of the loop before saving data? Are you checking EOF yourself somewhere in your code?

Comment: Is it possible that the first row is being treated as a header row and so ignored? You could try modifying your connection string to include `HDR=NO`, or play with that setting.

Comment: nah.. then he would still see the last data and first row missing

Comment: show the content of your while loop may help a lot.

Comment: Just wanted to check he wasn't simply looking at row counts rather than explicit data.

Comment: I've played with HDR and even IMEX just for the hell of it. Nothing has worked.

Comment: @JP_medevice, the issue is already present in the reader itself. I've stepped through and the while loop exits before reaching the last row. The data doesn't even get into the reader it seems like.

Comment: show your complete connection string

Comment: @Dalal How many rows are you reading?

Comment: @NoOne, I've updated it with how the string looks in code. The {0} gets replaced with the data path. It's obviously getting to the data path, because the first rows are imported.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, up to 10 or so rows usually. Not that many.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, the While loop contents don't actually matter in regard to the issue. The problem is already there in the Reader. If there are 5 rows to be read, the while loop will only iterate 4 times. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Dalal instead of using reader, can you try to fill a  DataTable and see if you get all rows?

Comment: Without looking at code, my assumption is that reader.Read() hits the -1 eof at current position (last character/row) since .Read() reads the next character/row, which will make it to get out of while loop without going through module inside.

Comment: Think we need to see the query which populates the reader and whether it uses a named range, unnamed range or just a sheet reference